# Run `composer update` in different PHP versions

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am working on a Laravel project. My `composer.json` file is like below.

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.8.6",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.10",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.21",
        "propaganistas/laravel-phone": "4.2.3",
        "spatie/db-dumper": "^2.15",
        "timehunter/laravel-google-recaptcha-v3": "~2.2.16",
        "webup/laravel-sendinblue": "~2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
      "repositories": {
        "packagist.org": {
          "type": "composer",
          "url": "https://packagist.org"
        }
      },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Initially I was using PHP `8.1`. I was getting below error.

```
  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires php ^7.1.3 but your php version (8.1.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - laravel/framework[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] require php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.1.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework 5.8.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev].
```

[image]

After that I changed my PHP version to `7.0`. Then I am getting below error while I am running `composer update` command.

```
Composer 2.3.0 dropped support for PHP <7.2.5 and you are running 7.0.33-57+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, please upgrade PHP or use Composer 2.2 LTS via "composer self-update --2.2". Aborting.
```

How can I run `composer update` command in this project ?

[image]

Comment: The command itself is telling you what to do, what do you not understand about it? `composer self-update --2.2`, and install `php 7.1.3` because that is what `composer.json` is needing...

Comment: If you require `"php": "^7.1.3",`, what makes you think that you can run this application with PHP 8? Also, PHP 7.0 is **horribly** outdated

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install php^7.1.3 after that install you need to change environment  path for php^7.1.3 after running command

Answer (score -1):

Yes you need to install xampp 7.1.30. Before this uninstall your old xampp. And delete xampp file in c disk.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why should one use a horribly outdated version of PHP, like 7.1.30?